# Using Javascript to insert emailaddress into a form field - comes out scrambled

Tags: javascript, email

I am using Dynamic Web, and have made a form where I want javascript to fill out some of the fields in advance.

It works fine with regular text. But when I try to input an email using this method, it comes out scrambled / encoded.

The JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $j('#Forhandler_Forhandlernr').val("2001 - Fyns Antenne og Elektronikcenter A/S");
  $j('#Forhandler_Forhandler').val("Roersvej 33 A, 5000 Odense C");
  $j('#Forhandler_Forhandler_email').val("fae@fae.dk"); 
< /script>
```

It is the

```
$j('#Forhandler_Forhandler_email').val("fae@fae.dk");
```

where it comes out as code for the individual letters:

```
&#102;&#97;&#101;&#64;&#102;&#97;&#101;&#46;&#100;&#107;
```

Comment: Is `$j` a reference to jQuery, or some other library?

Comment: There's quite likely an e-mail address obfuscating script that's encoding it like that.

Answer (score 0):

The library you're using encodes email addresses to the character code equivalent. If you put that result in an HTML file and viewed it in the browser it will show up as the email address.

It's a tool to prevent spambots from finding email addresses in the source code.